# Using $injector in AngularJS when integration testing (without using ngMock)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, integration-testing, karma-runner

I'm needing to setup some integration tests in AngularJS using Karma/Jasmine but having trouble, because when not using ngMock (since I want to hit the actual $http endpoints), there are no `module` or `inject` methods.

So how do I inject services into my tests?

I've tried `angular.injector.invoke(...)` but can't get it working, always comes back with an error like `Unknown provider: AuthServiceProvider <- AuthService`.

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't what you mean by "there are no module or inject methods." Can you add some sample code to your post?

Comment: Have a look: http://pastebin.com/cey8tPdG. This is a basic test in Angular using karma/jasmine. Result is `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module`, if you don't use ngMock module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
'use strict';

describe('Login User', function () {
    var app, LoginService;

    beforeEach(module('app')) ;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_LoginService_) {
        LoginService = _LoginService_;
    })) ;

   it('Should be logged in', function () {
       var isLoggedIn = LoginService.isUserLoggedIn();
       expect(isLoggedIn).toBeTruthy();
    });
 });
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module`

Comment: Can you post your karma config?

Comment: Ugh, I just tried something. I include the `angular-mocks.js` file in karma. But I don't include `ngMock`. And surprisingly, that works! I can now use `module` and `inject` within the karma/jasmine tests. I'm hoping this means that $httpBackend isn't being implemented. I'll give this further testing later to make sure I can run my integration tests.